# How to build Xcode iOS project using Apollo framwork to work with GraphQL

Tags: ios, xcode, graphql, apollo

I am working on an Xcode project that connects to a GraphQL API.  To do this, I'm using the [Apollo framework](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/) .

In my project, I've installed the cocoapod that includes the Apollo framework, and then added the following run script in Xcode:

```
if which apollo-codegen >/dev/null; then

  APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$(eval find $FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS -name "Apollo.framework" -maxdepth 1)"

  if [ -z "$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH" ]; then
    echo "warning: Couldn't find Apollo.framework in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS; make sure to add the framework to your project."
    exit 0
  fi

  cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/GraphQL"
  $APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate \
    $(find . -name '*.graphql') \
    --schema schema.json \
    --output Generated/GraphQLAPI.swift
else
  echo "Skipping Apollo code generation"
fi
```

This is how it looks in Xcode:

[image]

My directory structure in Xcode looks like this:

[image]

I then run the following command from Terminal:

```
npm install -g apollo-codegen
```

When I then try to build my Xcode project, I unfortunately get the following build error:

> /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The_Game-dfpiqreyqdjocaawjrfwhrxhdosf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/The Game.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/The Game.build/Script-7851AAFF2110C71000903FAD.sh: line 12: /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The_Game-dfpiqreyqdjocaawjrfwhrxhdosf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Apollo/Apollo.framework/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh: No such file or directory

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The build script has changed in recent versions of apollo ios, because apollo-codegen is now part of the new apollo cli. it should reference `check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh` instead.

Also make sure you use the latest version of apollo (currently `0.9.2`) by specifying the version in your podfile. You might also need to update your pod repo by running `pod repo update`.